# Every Riemannian metric on a two-dimensional sphere is euqal to a conformal factor times the natural metric on the sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry

I know of a theorem that states that every two-dimensional Riemannian manifold is locally conformally flat.

How to prove the global statement in the title?

Can I use the local theorem to prove the global statement?

The natural metric is $d s^2 = d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$.

---

Following Prof. Lee Mosher's suggestion,  I take a glance over Ahlfors' book **Conformal Invariants**. The uniformization theorem is proved in the last chapter and the statement in the title is a special case of this theorem.

The following form of the uniformization theorem is from the [note](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emarshall/preprints/uniformizationII.pdf) of Prof. Donald E. Marshall.

**The Uniformization Theorem (Koebe[1907]).**  Suppose $W$ is a simply connected Riemann surface. If Green’s function exists for $W$, then there is a one-to-one analytic map of $W$ onto the unit disk. If $W$ is compact, then there is a one-to-one analytic map of $W$ onto the sphere. If $W$ is not compact and if Green’s function does not exist for $W$, then there is a one-to-one analytic map of $W$ onto the complex plane.

Comment: This is a gigantic question. You are asking about a special case of the Riemann Mapping Theorem. There are books devoted to its proof, for example Ahlfors book [Conformal Invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lars_Ahlfors#Bibliography).

Comment: Thanks. @LeeMosher

Comment: What is "the natural metric" on the sphere? If you mean "isometric to" then the claim will be true, and false otherwise.

Comment: Be careful: Think of having a spherical balloon and squeezing it to introduce various bulges. This surface is diffeomorphic to a sphere, of course, but the metric is not a conformally factor times the standard metric; in particular, there are plenty of non-umbilic points. So definitions matter.

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is simply false.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike  Thank you.  Could you please give a counter example or more details?

Comment: Just take a nonconformal diffeomorphism $f: S^2\to S^2$ and the metric $f^*(ds^2)$, where $ds^2$ is the "natural metric."